# Elements not positioning properly in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Been pulling my hair out over this all day and decided to pimp my question out to the internets.

One of my page elements (the `"RRP:" label` contained in the `span .price-label` within the `div .old-price`) is for some reason refusing to position correctly when viewed in Chrome, but looks fine in Firefox and IE. It should be fairly obvious what I mean when viewing the page with Firefox/IE and then in Chrome.

If anyone can offer me a solution that correctly positions label in chrome and doesn't break the way the site looks in other browsers I'd be super grateful.

[here's an example of an offending page](http://www.wholesaleledlights.co.uk/dimmable-e27-3w-omni-led-clear-candle.html)

Edit : Dont have enough rep for my upvotes to show up, but most grateful for the help. Aparna's solution was a perfect fix. Cheers.

Comment: Please indicate where precisely the issue is (possibly a screenshot). That page appears to render properly for me in Chrome.

Comment: why are you applying the break after the label?.If you want the element to be occupy its own line give 'display:block'. and to have space at bottom give some margin at bottom with 'margin-bottom'

Comment: i see what you are talking about, format the old price the same way you formated the our price box. And you should really try and post your code and css so it makes things easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very bad practice to use `<br>` tag.So first remove the `<br>` tag after the label that has class as `price-label` and try below code-

Try This-

```
.price-label
{
  display:block;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your html to look like the following,

```
<div id="pricing">
        <li class="new-price">
            <div class="old-price" style="background-color: #3b6987; color: white;">
                <span class="price-label" style="text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 13px;">RRP:</span><br>

                <span id="old-price-1528"> £7.56 </span>
            </div>


            <div class="special-price">
                <span class="price-label">Our Price:</span><br>
                <span class="price-excluding-tax">
                    <span class="product-price" id="price-excluding-tax-1528" style="color: #c40000!important;"> £6.00 </span>
                </span>
                <span class="price-including-tax"> </span>
            </div>
        </li>
    </div>
```

And @Aparna has a good point, but the Html i posted will fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'd remove the `<br>`'s from the HTML.  In the CSS, add `.price-label { display: block; }` to obviate the need for the `<br>`'s. Also, change the `line-height` for `.old-price, .special-price`  from `0.6` to `1` to prevent those elements from collapsing.